# ¿Es posible traducir los botones de MessageBox en WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, messagebox

trabajo en WPF hace poco tiempo, y se me presentó la consulta, es posible traducir los botones de un `MensageBox` según la cultura? O simplemente forzar la traducción de alguna manera?

Por ejemplo,

```
public static bool AreYouSure(string text, string title)
{
    var result = MessageBox.Show(text,
        title,
        MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
        MessageBoxImage.Question);

    return result == MessageBoxResult.Yes;
}
```

En este caso, el mensaje se mostraría con los botones `Yes` y `No`, me gustaría lograr que fuesen `Sí` y `No`

Dentro de la [documentación de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8), no encontré nada al respecto, es esto posible sin tener que crear mi propia implementación de `MessageBox`?

Gracias!

Comment: Me parece que funciona dependiendo de la `Culture` que tengas como predeterminada en el `Thread` de la aplicación (que por defecto es el `Culture` predeterminado del equipo)

Comment: @Marc La solución es exactamente esa, no se como no se me ocurrió :P, si podes ponelo como respuesta!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que, estas UI por defecto cogen la [`Culture`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.8) del `Thread` de la aplicación, que por defecto es el `Culture` del sistema.

Debes modificar el `Culture` del `Thread` de la aplicación para que te lo traduzca en el idioma que quieres:

```
    var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES"); //Región España
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```

O modificar la región del equipo con el que estés trabajando.